# Error: project ID is required

Tags: truffle

I have a truffle project which was running on another machine without problem. But now I'm trying to npm install and I'm getting this error:

```
>truffle install

Error: project ID is required
    at Object.InvalidResponse (C:\Users\Home\Desktop\Authcoin-truffle\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\ethpm-registry\~\truffle-contract\~\web3\lib\web3\errors.js:35:1)
    at C:\Users\Home\Desktop\Authcoin-truffle\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\ethpm-registry\~\truffle-contract\~\web3\lib\web3\requestmanager.js:86:1
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (C:\Users\Home\Desktop\Authcoin-truffle\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\web3\lib\web3\httpprovider.js:128:1)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\Home\Desktop\Authcoin-truffle\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:64:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (C:\Users\Home\Desktop\Authcoin-truffle\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:354:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (C:\Users\Home\Desktop\Authcoin-truffle\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:509:1)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Home\Desktop\Authcoin-truffle\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:469:1)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1129:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! authcoin@1.0.0 postinstall: `truffle install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the authcoin@1.0.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Home\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-24T19_10_25_922Z-debug.log
```

This is what I'm getting when running "truffle version"

```
Truffle v5.1.14 (core: 5.1.14)
Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)
Node v10.16.0
Web3.js v1.2.1
```

I found similar error in infura related questions but I'm not using infura at all.
So how can I get rid of this error?

Comment: What does truffel install do? usually npm install!

Answer (score 1):

Probably it's the `truffle-config.js` or `truffle.js` file that cause the error, in some truffle boxes the Infura's service link is set without ProjectId in it e.g. `https://ropsten.infura.io/<your infura key>` so when you try to compile they throw this error. Please set up your Infura link properly on Ropsten and Rinkeby as [Project ID is required](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/79215/project-id-is-required/79219) or remove them it you do not need them.